# Applying PolynomialTransformation2D

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

Using MATLAB, I calculate a PolynomialTransformation2D object between two images like so:

```
transMat = fitgeotrans(movingPoints,fixedPoints,'polynomial',3);
```

This gives me a geometric transformation, which I can use to register one image (the moving image - thats where the movingPoints came from) to another image (the fixed image - thats where the fixed points came from). Therefore, I can also use this transformation to map points (called `A`) from the moving image to the fixed image (then called `B`).

With other transformation objects like from class "projective2d" this works as follows:

```
B = transformPointsForward(transMat ,A);
```

For "PolynomialTransformation2D" this however does not work. The only thing I have found was:

```
B = transformPointsInverse(transMat ,A);
```

But then the points in B have negative coordinates and obviously are wrong. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: The second paragraph is very confusing. Can you improve on that one?

Comment: what exactly is the second paragraph to you? Starting with "With other transformation objects"? I am not sure why you think it is very confusing. Can you be more specific? Have you understood what I want to do?

Comment: The "What I want to  (...)' part is grammatically incorrect and incomprehensible to me. I'm not familiar with the matlab functions, so I don't understand what you're doing. Others might be able to help, if they understand the question.

Comment: Hmm...well, I tried to rephrase that sentence. I hope its clearer now. Without knowing MATLAB however, I am afraid its difficult to help anyway :(

Comment: Im quite versed in matlab, just not in image related questions. Sentence is much clearer now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just reverse the transformation, i.e. calculate:

```
transMat = fitgeotrans(fixedPoints,movingPoints,'polynomial',3);
```

And then transform the points using `tranformPointInverse`.

The reason you don't have `transformPointsForward` is that as opposed to similarity, affine, and projective transformations, the polynomial transformation is not trivially invertible. Remember that, like you said, the transformation object represents the transformation from the 'moving' image to the 'fixed' one. However, the polynomial itself describes the calculation of coordinates in the **'moving'** image based on coordinates in the 'fixed' image.

So, as written in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/images.geotrans.polynomialtransformation2d-class.html?searchHighlight=PolynomialTransformation2d), underlying the transformation object are 2 sets of polynomial coefficients (`A` and `B`), such that:

```
U = A(1) + A(2).*X + A(3).*Y + A(4).*X.*Y + A(5).*X.^2 + A(6).*Y.^2 +...
V = B(1) + B(2).*X + B(3).*Y + B(4).*X.*Y + B(5).*X.^2 + B(6).*Y.^2 +...
```

where `X` and `Y` are the coordinates in the 'fixed' image and `U` and `V` are the coordinates in the 'moving' image.

Looking at these you can see that it's easy to transform points 'backward' - you just plugin the values instead of `X` and `Y` in the formulas above and get `U` and `V`. However, it's not as easy (and not always possible) to transform 'forward' - given `X` and `Y` solve the equations above (which may be 3rd - 5th order) to get a unique solution for `U` and `V`.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer. However, I still do not really understand that the polynomial describes the calculation of coordinates in the 'moving' image based on coordinates in the 'fixed' image. When I transform my moving image, I must calculate the coordinates of points from the moving image in the fixed image, don't I? How can it then be that to "transform forward" is not always possible? I think, I get sth confused here...

Comment: Let's say you want to transform the moving image (denote `M(x,y)`) to the fixed coordinate system and get a new image called `F(x,y)`. You'll have to do the following: for each point `(X,Y)` in the **fixed** coordinate system calculate the value of `F(X,Y)` according to the corresponding pixel in the **moving** image `M(U,V)`. That's why all you need is a way to calculate `U` and `V` based on `X` and `Y`. [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/remap/remap.html) is a nice explanantion from OpenCV about remapping images.

Comment: I think I understood now. They use "inverse warping", as it is called here: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~dramanan/teaching/cs116_fall08/lec/warping.pdf. That is, the values in the warped image are calculated by mapping the coordinates of the warped image into the moving image, basically meaning that you transform coordinates from the fixed to the moving image. // (only saw your comment after I wrote, but I think its supporting what I wrote)